# Number of vertices increased after copying from graph to vector

Tags: c++, boost, adjacency-list

I'm trying to copy all vertices from `boost::adjacency_list` to `std::vector`.
But after doing it, in `std::vector` amount of vertices increasing twice.
Example of code:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS> revision_graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<revision_graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex;

revision_graph graph;
int verticesNumb = num_vertices(graph);
std::cout << "NUMBER OF VERTICES IN GRAPH: " << verticesNumb << "\n";
std::vector< vertex > *rVector = new std::vector< vertex >(verticesNumb);
std::cout << "VECTOR SIZE AFTER INIT: " << rVector->size();
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, graph, revision_graph)
{
    rVector->push_back(v);
}
std::cout << "VECTOR SIZE AFTER COPYING: " << rVector->size();
```

Output:

- NUMBER OF VERTICES IN GRAPH:  139
- VECTOR SIZE AFTER INIT:  139
- VECTOR SIZE AFTER COPYING:  278

I've tried different way of 'copying' vertices to vector, but result was the same:

```
boost::graph_traits< revision_graph >::vertex_iterator vi, vi_end;
for(boost::tie(vi, vi_end) = boost::vertices(graph); vi != vi_end; ++vi)
{
    rVector->push_back(*vi);
}
```

So, how should I do this?
I'd be very thankful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created the vector, it already is of size `verticesNumb`.
Then you `push_back` another `verticesNumb` elements, which totals in `2 * verticesNumb`.

Consider this simple example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int size = 100;
    std::vector<int> vec(size);

    for (int i = 0; i<100; ++i)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**[output](https://ideone.com/SMDPn2)**

```
200
```

Solution: Do not set the initial size, rather `reserve` it:

```
std::vector< vertex > *rVector = new std::vector< vertex >();
rVector->reserve(verticesNumb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are initializing vector with size `verticesNumb`

```
std::vector< vertex > *rVector = new std::vector< vertex >(verticesNumb);
```

later on you are adding to the end of vector with `push_back`. Thats why its two time more than you expect.

Use reserve on vector like that:

```
std::vector< vertex > *rVector = new std::vector< vertex >();
rVector ->reserve(verticesNumb);
```